# How to save image in database without ruin the picture?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, picturebox

I have a problem regarding on saving the image on database using BLOB data type, it save the image successfully but when i retrieve it using my picture box it ruins my image. ill show you the screenshot on my application. I am using vb.net.

[image: img was ruin.]

this is my codes on **saving image file in blob data type.**

```
Dim filename As String = Me.OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    Dim FileSize As UInt32

    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
    conn = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user=root;password=;database=ticketing_system;")
    conn.Open()

    Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
    Me.PbPicture.Image = Image.FromFile(Me.OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    Me.PbPicture.Image.Save(mstream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

    Dim arrImage() As Byte = mstream.GetBuffer()


    FileSize = mstream.Length
    Dim sqlcmd As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
    Dim sql As String
    mstream.Close()

    ' DBconn.Close()

    sql = "INSERT INTO clientreports(img)VALUES(@File)"
    Try
        ' DBconn.Open()
        With sqlcmd
            .CommandText = sql

            .Connection = conn
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@File", arrImage)
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    Finally

        conn.Close()

    End Try
```

here is my code on displaying my image on picturebox.

```
Dim strSQL As String
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
    conn = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user=root;password=;database=ticketing_system;")


    Dim SQLConnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
    'Dim connection As New SqlConnection("connection string here")
    Dim command As New MySqlCommand("SELECT img FROM errdeschis where err_id='31'", conn)

    conn.Open()

    Dim pictureData As Byte() = DirectCast(command.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())
    conn.Close()

    Dim picture As Image = Nothing
    'Create a stream in memory containing the bytes that comprise the image.
    Using stream As New IO.MemoryStream(pictureData)

        'Read the stream and create an Image object from the data.    
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream)
    End Using
```

please guys help me.

Comment: Have you verified the length on the way in vs. on the way out? That might be helpful in trying to diagnose what's breaking down.

Comment: no sir.I haven't, by the way sir how to verify the length on vs?

Comment: anyway do you know how to convert the image before storing it on database?

Comment: What I meant by the "length on vs" is actual the length before the image was put in the database compared to the length after it was retrieved from the database. It looks like your conversion is probably fine, but I'm wondering if the BLOB type has some length to it that your picture is exceeding. That's why I was curious about the length.

Answer (score 1):

OKAY.Use MEDIUMBLOB or LONGBLOB for the field.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried psren `s answer?

changed BLOB to LONGBLOB

It works for me!

Comment: Im sorry for that but I was just clarifying the solution to his/her problem because I also encountered his/her problem and found psren `s answer and since he/she isnt responding to this. I just wanted to make sure that he/she already checked psren `s answer.

Comment: Sorry if i`ve made a mistake I wont do it again

Comment: Alright. Make sure you understand how to use Stack Overflow. If you want to promote an already existing answer, just please vote on it - that's why this functionality was made.

Comment: Great, have a nice day! :)